# How to check if two ImmutableJS Maps have the same keys?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Is there a simple way to check if two ImmutableJS Maps have the same set of keys? Same number of keys and same key values (assuming simple string keys).

Comment: Are you talking about [*ECMAScript 2015 Maps*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-objects)? If so, [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) has some useful information to get you started. Check out the *size*, *forEach* and *has* methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare between two maps:

```
var bool = map1.equals(map2)
```

And if its only keys you want:

```
var bool = map1.keySeq().equals(map2.keySeq())
```